# I'm trying to create new array of array from one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create new array of array from one array,

How to make

var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];

become

var array = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8'], ['9', '10']];

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple loop with [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to update the same array.

```js
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
  size = 2;

// iterate upto the length(which is dynamic)
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  // remove the 2 elements and insert as an array element
  // at the same index
  array.splice(i, 0, array.splice(i, size));

console.log(array);
```

---

In case you want to generate a new array then use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```js
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
  size = 2,
  res = [];

// iterate over the array where increment index by the size
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += size)
  // push the subarray
  res.push(array.slice(i, i + size));

console.log(res);
```

An ES6 alternative with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method:

```js
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
  size = 2;

var res = Array.from({
  // create an array of size based on the chunk size
  length: Math.ceil(array.length / size)
  // iterate and generate element by the index
}, (_, i) => array.slice(i * size, i * size + size))

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
var newArray = [];
var i,j,chunk = 2;
for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    newArray.push(array.slice(i,i+chunk));
}
console.log(newArray);
```